# Mysql - Get auto increment id on actual insert

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the auto increment id of a field in a mysql table and use it in the same insert?

e.g

assuming the new id here would be 2, an evaluated statement would look as follows

"insert into table (field1) values( 'random-2')"

I know it's possible for me to return this in the code and run another insert, but I wondered if there was a quicker way to 'compute' this during the insert?

1 thought I had was "insert into table (field1) values( 'random' + (select max(id) FROM table) + 1)"

but I'm worried about possible issues with multiple inserts occurring at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible and this has been asked many times before. Look to the right of this question and follow some links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use current auto_increment value as basis for another field in the same INSERT query - is this possible in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767161/use-current-auto-increment-value-as-basis-for-another-field-in-the-same-insert-qu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql Getting the same auto_increment value into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297462/mysql-getting-the-same-auto-increment-value-into-another)

Comment: believe it or not I did search but couldn't find what I was looking for :S Still getting used to using SO though so apologies for the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. You're gonna have to update the entry afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm worried about possible issues with multiple inserts occurring at the same time

That's only part of the problem - insert ids are only suposed to be unique - not contiguous.

If you want to do it in a single call from the application then use a stored procedure to encapsulate the insert+update or use a trigger to fire an update on insert. Or use a sequence generator instead of an autoincrement.